# Is dbo the default schema when querying if it is not specified?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

If I query a table which exists in two different schemas but has the same name what determines which table is used?

For example I have table `Bar` which exists in both `dbo` and `foo`, if I execute the statement below which one is returned:

```
SELECT * FROM Bar
```

I thought this was determined by the users default schema but doesn't appear to be the case.

I ask because I have found queries written by someone else who is not specifying the schema name yet the database being queried has the same tables in different schemas for ETL.

Comment: Testing it with my login it was set to `dbo` and that's the result I got. I switched it to the other schema and still got results from `dbo`.

Comment: http://rextester.com/XOCC63073

Comment: In any case, it's good practice to always reference tables/views/objects with `schema.table`

Comment: Windows authentication though my login is part of an active directory group so that's likely why it didn't change

Comment: See this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/04/03/name-resolution-default-schema-implicit-schema-part-iii/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx):

> The value of DEFAULT_SCHEMA is ignored if the user is a member of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role. All members of the sysadmin fixed server
>   role have a default schema of dbo.

So it seems the account used where the default schema is not working is a sysadmin role member. The default schema of the dbo user is always dbo and cannot be changed.

The best practice is generally is to schema-qualify object references to avoid ambiguity and improve performance.